# Windows 10 asks for updates ignoring update GPO

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, group-policy

Why Windows 10 asks user to update their computer also if they are under domain with GPO set to automatically update? This did not happen with Win 7 and I did not change any GPO about updates.

These are my GPO settings
[image]

Consider that the update at the end is working, but what I'm asking is why now with Win10 a question is shown to user to let he decide to do or not to do updates?

Comment: How Windows handles updates changed slightly with Windows 10.  You have to use WSUS if you want to prevent updates from being downloaded.

Comment: I have a WSUS server, the problem is that users are asked to do the update with a notification... with Win7 updates were silently done.

Comment: We need more information on the Windows Update settings you have configured your clients to have.  Simply saying it worked on Windows 7 is not enough information.

Comment: I updated my question.